# Apple subscription for customer

Tags: licensing, ios, apple

When developing an iOS application (freelance) for a customer, how do you handle the iOS Developer Subscription?

On the one hand, I have no problem submitting the app using my own subscription.
On the other hand, the subscription is per year which means the customer would be dependent on me actually renewing my subscription every year.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on who owns the application.

If the application, copyright and IP are under the ownership of the client, then it should be done under their licence, you can not be responsible for the application once your term with the client is complete.

However, if you retain ownership of the application, then you should be held responsible for the subscription and life cycle of the application.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is what we do and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

For my clients, I have them create an apple developer account of their own, and then give me their agent account creds to log in with and create profiles and submit apps.

This is especially true if you're building them a paid app. You probably don't want to be in the middle of their financial relationship with Apple.